# Can not alter/add data on shopify paid plan store by unlisted public app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am facing some weird issue in Shopify app development. I have created app which is working fine on Development store. it is able to add some data on development store.

But for testing purpose I have offered this app to the merchants to test this app on their live store having activated Shopify Paid plan. But app can not add any data. Post/Put requests are auto converted to Get requests.

I have created couple of apps those are published on App store and in past they were being used by Active Paid Plan merchants before app has been published without any issue.

Is there something changed on Shopify side. or I am missing something this time ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How can post/put request get auto-converted to get request? The protocol is being set by you. Can you post the APIs you are using and what is the response that you are getting?

Comment: In the post/put request response is just like get request. and it is happening on live stores only it is working fine on development stores.

Comment: Can you share what response you are getting and which API you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

every put/post request's endpoint should be on .myshopify version of domain.

I was passing primary domain. and it was working fine in dev stores as dev store. because in dev stores .myshopify version domain and primary domains are same.

I did not get this issue for so long. it was a silly mistake but stops app functionality.

Posting answer just because other people would not make such a blunder.